# Is Simultaneous Duplicate and Extend possible on a laptop?

Tags: laptop, display, duplicate

My laptop is hooked up to a SmartBoard projector with a 9-pin cable. I've recently added a second monitor (HDMI). I can extend the monitor OR project to the SmartBoard - but have not been able to do both at the same time. Any thoughts? It would make teaching a half in-person half virtual class so much easier.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly this 9-pin cable is exactly by editing your question?  You should also [edit] your question and include a screenshot of your Display configuration within Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own. If you don't know what a 9-pin cble is you probably couldn't have helped me. https://www.eltima.com/images/upload/sec/pinout/6.jpg